# jQuery - Get input value with specific class name

Tags: jquery

How to get all values of input type text with a specific class?

I tried this code. But it's not showing the expected answer.

```
$('input .classname').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 8):

This should select all input fields of type text with the class "classname".

```
$('input[type="text"].classname').each(function () {
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 3):

One way is to assign a class for all your `input` elements, that way it will not interfere with unwanted `input` elements.

For example when you don't need to get all the `input` elements in the `DOM`

```js
$('.test').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class='test' value='wanted data'/>
<input value='unwanted data'/>
```

Comment: Yes! sometimes a gallery component creates unwanted duplicates of div's, had to use class names like this to ignore the duplicate hidden fields..

Answer (score 0):

i think `keyup` is what you are looking for

```js
$('.classname').keyup(function() {
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' class='classname'>
```